# The pause duration is (very)longer when number items are huge

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity, designer-workflow

We have a custom (SPD)workflow(manually starting) on a custom list which has 7000 to 8000 items and growing. "Pause For Duration" action is used to pause the workflow for 5mins and roughly 30 to 50 workflows would be under execution at a given point of time. Of the above around 10 – 15 workflows are those that could last for 21 days with multiple pauses and the maximum Pause is for 7 days.

Below are the workflow configurations:

1. workflow-eventdelivery-throttle is 25
2. workitem-eventdelivery-batchsize is 125
3. workflow-eventdelivery-timeout is 5
4. job-workflow is 3mins.
5. No of WFEs is 4
6. No of App.Server is 1

Now, the issue is that it works perfectly when the list size is less however the pause duration is (very)longer for the above mentioned list.

Is there a way to solve this issue without causing any potential performance issues.

Comment: does it help if we increase the batchsize?